# How to add additional item in JSON String in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

```
execute(req : any): any{
var stReq = JSON.stringify(req);
}
```

now i want to add additional item (eg.  "Cityname": "angular2City"` inside stReq or req ??

Comment: stReq["propertyName"] = value; This is plain js, not angular related.

Answer (score 0):

```
execute(req : string): string {
    var jReq = JSON.parse(req)
    jReq['cityName1'] = 'Paris';
    jReq['cityName2'] = 'Sydney';
    return JSON.stringify(jReq);
}
```

I am new to Angular so I still searched for it as an angular thing, though as Alejandro Lora mentioned, this is really just javascript.  Your code seems to start with JSON, but your question is how to append to a JSON string, so that is what my example does.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely JSON/JavaScript related. Basically you can't add any item while your **req** is in *string* format. So you need to do all kind of manipulations before converting it into string.

```
execute(req : any): any { 
       req['Cityname'] = 'New york'; 
       var stReq = JSON.stringify(req); 
    }
```